# Javascript FOR loop inside of an array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-visualization

I have been avoiding javascript for a while now but need to use it for a google chart I am using. My original code looks like this...

```
echo "function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Machines Total'  ],

      [ '$Day[6]', $Hour_Tot[7].$Min_Tot[7] ], 
      [ '$Day[5]', $Hour_Tot[6].$Min_Tot[6] ], 
      [ '$Day[4]', $Hour_Tot[5].$Min_Tot[5] ],
      [ '$Day[3]', $Hour_Tot[4].$Min_Tot[4] ],
      [ '$Day[2]', $Hour_Tot[3].$Min_Tot[3] ],
      [ '$Day[1]', $Hour_Tot[2].$Min_Tot[2] ],
      [ '$Day[0]', $Hour_Tot[1].$Min_Tot[1] ]

      ]);";
```

This code works just fine, and has been tested. What I am trying to do now is have
the chart become more dynamic so a user can enter in a number and the chart can ouput
the data for the number of days. So I need to add in a for loop. This is what I got so
far.

```
echo "function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Machine L1'  ],
      for (count = 1, DayNumber = 0; count == 7; ++count, ++DayNumber ) 
  document.write([ '$Day[DayNumber]', $Hour_Tot[count].$Min_Tot[count]],);
       ]);";
```

This code does not work. I do not understand how to use the document.write to output
the 7 lines I need to replicate the above code.

Comment: Why dont you use PHP for that iteration?

Comment: what @NULL said. echoing javascript from php like that is crazy, man.

Comment: google charts is echoing the javascript in the php. I am just using there format.

Comment: I apologize I was the one who echoed the javascript like that. I will see if i can change that up as well.

Comment: try writing your javascript functions in a separate file, then echoing just the data from php to a javascript variable, which you can then use in a function. that way you can keep js and php entirely separate.

Comment: @sgroves The reason I sugest that is because of OP's question. Also maybe OP just had a type-o and actually wanted to do so (using PHP and JS together). But when that i said, I wouldn't suggest anyone to mix frontend with backend - ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not going to work because you're putting a for loop inside an array declaration.
You should do the following...

```
echo "function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', 'Machine L1'  ],";
for ($count = 1, $DayNumber = 0; $count <= 7; ++$count, ++$DayNumber ) {
  echo "  [ '$Day[$DayNumber]', $Hour_Tot[$count].$Min_Tot[$count]],";
}
echo "]);";
```

Or you can also handle that using javascript, it should looks like:

```
echo "var arr = [['Date', 'Machine L1']];
  for(var i=1;i<=7;i++) {
    arr.push([{$Day}[i-1], {$Hour_Tot}[i].toString()+{$Min_Tot}[i].toString()]);
  }
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
";
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thanks for the quick answers. Did not work at first, but I added <=. Thanks.